# How do I Interpret the Cardinality of a Sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, probability-theory, set-theory

My professor has given us a take-home exam with a question regarding the cardinality of sequences. He defines a sequence as (verbatim): $$\text{given } A \in \{\text{sets}\}, (s \text{ is a sequence} \iff s : \mathbb{N} \to A)$$
I am supposed to evaluate the truth of the following statement: $$s, t \in \{\text{sequences}\} \Rightarrow |s| = |t|$$
How am I to understand the cardinality of a sequence? If the cardinality depends on the domain, then I suppose all sequences would be of equal cardinality (countably infinite). On the other hand, if the cardinality has more to do with the codomain, it seems obvious that no two sequences are *necessarily* of the same cardinality. Any clarification would be very much appreciated.

Comment: It's a bit hard to answer without knowing your formal definition of a function $s : \mathbb N \to A$. One common definition is that a function $s: \mathbb N \to A$ is a subset of the Cartesian product $\mathbb N \times A$ having the property that for each $n \in \mathbb N$ there exists a unique $a \in A$ such that $(n,a) \subset s$. Are you using some such formal definition like that? If so, the answer is clear: $|s|=|\mathbb N|$ for all functions with domain $\mathbb N$. Or are you using something else?

Comment: My professor defines a function as: $$\text{given } A, B \in \{\text{sets}\}, (f : A \to B \iff (r \text{ is a relation from } A \text{ to } B) \land (\forall x \in A, \exists ! y \in B \ni (x, y) \in f))$$

Comment: Based in this definition, it seems that your reasoning is correct-- there must be a $y$ in $B$ for every $x$ in $A$ such that $f$ is at least injective (and likely bijective).

Comment: Yes, my definition and yours are identical. A relation from $A$ to $B$ is, literally, a subset of $A \times B$.

Comment: If $f: A \rightarrow B$ is a subset of $AxB$ the cardinality of $f$ does not look that of $A$.